# PHP DOMDocument: getElementsbyTagName('img') not work

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to grab an img tag inside a html. The HTML looks somewhat like this:

```html
<img style='width:198px;height:279px;'            class='featureImg'             src='image-loader.gif'            data-src='http://somesites.com/med/1455.jpg'            alt="Picture">
```

Now I want to grab img src `http://somesites.com/med/1455.jpg`.

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($divs as $div){
     if(preg_match_all('/\bfeatureImg\b/', $div->getAttribute('class'))) {
         $links = $div->getElementsByTagName('img');
         foreach($links as $link){
                $li = $link->getAttribute('data-src');

                echo ($li.'<br>');

}}}
```

And doesn't work... Anybody help??

Comment: shouldnt it be `$link->getAttribute('src');` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This already gives you the images:

```
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

So if the `preg_match_all` matches, you can get the 'data-src' attribute:

```
$html = <<<SOURCE
<img style='width:198px;height:279px;'            class='featureImg'             src='image-loader.gif'            data-src='http://somesites.com/med/1455.jpg'            alt="Picture">
SOURCE;
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    if (preg_match_all('/\bfeatureImg\b/', $div->getAttribute('class'))) {
        echo $div->getAttribute('data-src');
    }
}
```

Will result in:

> http://somesites.com/med/1455.jpg